# Efficiently counting strength of relationship between rows in Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table that looks similar to this:

```
 session_id | sku 
------------|-----
     a      |  1
     a      |  2
     a      |  3
     a      |  4
     b      |  2
     b      |  3
     c      |  3
```

I want to pivot this into a table similar to this:

```
 sku1 | sku2 | score
------|------|------
  1   |  2   |   1
  1   |  3   |   1
  1   |  4   |   1
  2   |  3   |   2
  2   |  4   |   1
  3   |  4   |   1
```

The idea is to store a denormalised table that allows one to look up for a given sku, what other skus are related to sessions it has been related to, and how many times both skus are related to the same session.

What algorithms, patterns or strategies could you suggest for implementing this in PostgreSQL or other technologies?

I realise that this kind of lookup can be done on the original table using counts, or using a facetting search engine. However, I want to make the reads more performant, and just want to keep the overall statistics. The idea is that I will be performing this pivot regularly on the newest few thousand rows in the first table, then storing the result in the second. I'm only concerned with approximate statistics for the second table.

I've got some SQL that works, but VERY slowly. Also looking into the potential for using a graph database of some sort, but wanted to avoid adding another technology for a small part of the app.

**Update:** The SQL below seems performant enough. I can convert 1.2 million rows in the first table (tags) into 250k rows in the second table (product_relations) with around 2-3k variations of sku in about 5 minutes on my iMac. I will realistically be denormalising only up to 10k rows per day. Question is whether this is actually the best approach. Seems a little dirty to me.

```
BEGIN;
    CREATE
    TEMPORARY TABLE working_tags(tag_id int, session_id varchar, sku varchar) ON COMMIT DROP;

    INSERT INTO working_tags
    SELECT id,
           session_id,
           sku
    FROM tags
    WHERE time < now() - interval '12 hours'
      AND processed_product_relation IS NULL
      AND sku IS NOT NULL LIMIT 200000;

    CREATE
    TEMPORARY TABLE working_relations (sku1 varchar, sku2 varchar, score int) ON COMMIT DROP;

    INSERT INTO working_relations
    SELECT a.sku AS sku1,
           b.sku AS sku2,
           count(DISTINCT a.session_id) AS score
    FROM working_tags AS a
    INNER JOIN working_tags AS b ON a.session_id = b.session_id
    AND a.sku < b.sku
    WHERE a.sku IS NOT NULL
      AND b.sku IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY a.sku,
             b.sku;

    UPDATE product_relations
    SET score = working_relations.score+product_relations.score
    FROM working_relations
    WHERE working_relations.sku1 = product_relations.sku1
      AND working_relations.sku2 = product_relations.sku2;

    INSERT INTO product_relations (sku1, sku2, score)
    SELECT working_relations.sku1,
           working_relations.sku2,
           working_relations.score
    FROM working_relations
    LEFT OUTER JOIN product_relations ON (working_relations.sku1 = product_relations.sku1
                                          AND working_relations.sku2 = product_relations.sku2)
    WHERE product_relations.sku1 IS NULL;

    UPDATE tags
    SET processed_product_relation = TRUE
    WHERE id IN
        (SELECT tag_id
         FROM working_tags);

  COMMIT;
```

Comment: Where does `sku` come from? How do you get from `session_id` and `product_id` to `sku`? It isn't clear how the two tables are connected. Is this a crosstab/pivot, or something more complicated?

Comment: Updated the column name in the first table in the question. the first table has the sku. In the second table I wold like to have the sku, the another sku that appears in the same sessions, then the count of sessions that they are both in together.

Comment: So, rephrasing: "For every pairing of SKUs, find the count of sessions in which both SKUs appear". Right?

Comment: Correct. Ignoring pairings of SKUs that do not appear in the same session. Have updated the question again with more performant SQL that does what I want.

Comment: your SQL doesn't bear much relation to the sample data you posted. If you're looking to optimize a query, post on dba.stackexchange.com with *proper sample data* that *matches the query* or queries. The answer given below matches the sample data and should work well on a reasonable data set. You can subset the data with `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ... AS SELECT ...` commands, possibly then creating indexes on the temp tables, if you're working only on a tiny subset of a very big table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've interpreted your intention correctly (per comments) this should do it:

```
SELECT
  s1.sku AS sku1,
  s2.sku AS sku2,
  count(session_id)
FROM session s1
INNER JOIN session s2 USING (session_id)
WHERE s1.sku < s2.sku
GROUP BY s1.sku, s2.sku
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2e0b2/1

In other words: Self-join session, then find all pairings of SKUs for each session ID, excluding ones where the left is greater than or equal to the right in order to avoid repeating pairings - if we have `(1,2,count)` we don't want `(2,1,count)` as well. Then group by the SKU pairings and count how many rows are found for each pairing.

You may want to `count(distinct session_id)` instead, if your SKU pairings can repeat and you want to exclude duplicates. There will probably be more efficient ways to do that, but that's the simplest.

An index on at least `session_id` will be very useful. You may also want to mess with planner cost parameters to make sure it chooses a good plan - in particular, make sure `effective_cache_size` is accurate and `random_page_cost` vs `seq_page_cost` reflects your caching and I/O costs. Finally, throw as much `work_mem` at it as you can afford.

If you're creating a materialized view, just `CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE whatever AS SELECT ...`. . That way you minimise the numer of writes/rewrites/overwrites.

Comment: @mike The "Text to table" feature is a lifesaver when people post pretty-printed table output like this in questions; saves endless hassle turning it back into `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT`.